# Sprite Kit SKLabel not showing up over background picture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im trying to start a menu screen for my game and I created a SKLabel that is a supposed to be in the middle of my screen. But the problem is that it is not showing up. Only my background is showing up. I don't where to start, I thought it might have something to do with the z position but Im not sure. Here is my code

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    let waterWorksBackgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "WaterWorksBackground")
    waterWorksBackgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.width / 2 - 100)



    let startGameButton = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Heavy ")
    startGameButton.name = "startGame"
    startGameButton.color = UIColor.blueColor()
    startGameButton.text = "Start Game"
    startGameButton.fontSize = 65
    startGameButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2 + 100)



    //Adding to view
    self.addChild(startGameButton)
    self.addChild(waterWorksBackgroundImage)

}
```

Also in my console I get an error that says "2016-04-04 19:55:59.021 Waterworks2d[7829:1362855] CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom" Im not sure if that has anything to do with it but thanks!

Comment: Where is the error, and did you try changing the z position?

Comment: Ignore that error - it's cropping up for everyone and there's loads of threads about it on the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: you say you're not sure abut the zPosition, yet you haven't set the zPositions in your code - any particular reason why?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the order that you are adding the items.  Since you add the background first, then the other, it is on top of it.

Reverse to this:

```
//Adding to view
self.addChild(waterWorksBackgroundImage)
self.addChild(startGameButton)
```

and or add

```
startGameButton.zposition = 2
```

Hope that helps.